# How to correctly increment a returned iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I have an input iterator `CSVIterator` as defined in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c/1120224#1120224).

In my program, I now want to return such an iterator in a function and use it in my `main()`. The iterator is returned and I can access its contents. But when trying to iterate, I encounter a segmentation fault. Iterating within the returning function works.

I have two questions:

1. Why do I run into a seg fault? I thought about it being a problem of scope, but shouldn't then already the access to the iterator's contents lead to a segmentation fault?
2. How can my problem be fixed? The idea is to switch the opened files within a bigger loop at the correct iteration and always start at the beginning of that particular file. I come from a Python background and `yield`ing one line of the file after the other feels natural to me, but maybe it's not recommended in C++?

Here's the code

```
// For the definition of CSVIterator, see
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120224/2525159
CSVIterator fileIter(int time)
{
    std::string tstring = std::to_string(time);
    std::string ext = ".csv";
    std::ifstream file(tstring + ext);
    CSVIterator iter(file);
    // This would work:
    // ++iter;
    return iter;
}

int main()
{
    CSVIterator csvit;
    for (i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        if (i%20 == 0) {
            csvit = fileIter(i);
        }

        // I can access the iterator's contents
        // like (*csvit)[0] correctly.
        // However,iterating in here doesn't work.
        ++csvit; // seg fault here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because `file` is a *local variable*. That means that you are iterating over something that has gone out of scope (when the function terminated), this provokes **Undefined Behavior**, which explains the crash.

---

Notice how in the answer you linked, `file` is declared inside `main()`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Defining the file within `main()` now worked.